# Spring JPA Query Creation - Using By with a Predicate

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, predicate

I would like to create a Spring Data JPA query that uses a default criterion and a dynamic predicate.

For example using Customer entity:

`findByFirstnameIn(List<String> names, Predicate predicate);`

I can't find similar examples in the [Spring Data JPA documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

Another solution would be to use do

`findAll(predicate.and(customer.firstname.in(names)))`

but I would like to avoid this additional line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second approach is the correct way to do it. There is a similar feature request you might want to keep an eye on
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1524